# How to modify jquery validate to make it work online?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I've made a simple system of validation using jquery validator 1.8. Offline (xampp for mac os 1.7.3) works like a charm. As i get online the validation gets mad. 
The normal behavior on the checked field (a username) is that, using the php file, the username is live checked to be unique in the database.
Online, the check is not done until you go on the field, exit from it and return to it. (This is normal) Then it begin to check (and seems to work) but when all goes well i see anyway an error message that is "1" instead of nothing, and it get considered an error by the validator, stopping the submit of the form....
Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<!-- jquery //-->   
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<!-- jquery validazioni
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-validation-1.8.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 //-->   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsBetta/messaggiErrore.js"></script>  
<!-- datepicker lingua italiana //-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/linguaIT/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>
<!-- script MIEI (validazione e funzioni) //-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsBetta/funzioni.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsBetta/registrazione.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stile.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
</head>

<body>
<form action="registrazioneDB.php" id="insertUtenteForm" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <label for="nome_utente">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome_utente" id="nome_utente" maxlength="30"autocomplete="off">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
      <input id="bottoneSubmit" name="bottoneSubmit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Registrati">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**registrazione.js:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){        

    var nome_utente;

    jQuery('#insertUtenteForm').validate({ 
        rules: 
        {
            nome_utente: 
                {required: true,
                remote: { url:"AdMin/usrAvailCk.php", async:false }}
        },
        messages: {
            nome_utente: { remote: " Username non disponibile"}
        },
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                alert("Si prega di riempire correttamente i campi obbligatori, evidenziati con l'asterisco.");
                validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                }
        },  
});
return false;
});
```

**usrAvailCk.php**

```
<?php
include "connessione.php";

$nome_utente=$_GET['nome_utente'];

$queryUserAvailable = "SELECT * FROM utente where nome_utente='$nome_utente'";
$rsUserAvailable = connetti($queryUserAvailable);


if(mysql_num_rows($rsUserAvailable) == 0){
$valid=true;
}
else{
$valid=false;
}


echo json_encode($valid);
?>
```

**messaggiErrore.js**

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
required: " *",
email: " *",
equalTo: " *",
maxlength: jQuery.validator.format(" *"),
minlength: jQuery.validator.format(" *"),
remote: " *",
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// imposto i dettagli dei messaggi di validazione
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;}, " *");
//$.validator.messages.required = ' *';
//$.validator.messages.email=' *';
});
```

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser... it does not care if the file is online on a server or local on your hard drive... **as long as** it can find the files.  Are you sure the URL paths to the JavaScript files are correct?  Did you upload the JavaScript files to the correct location?  What JavaScript console errors are you getting?

Comment: The urls are correct for the control is correctly done. The problem is just it doesn't seems to Reach the 'correct' state. When a correct value is written in the field, the validator gives this error with message '1'... According to your hint, problem lays in the php part... But where? (no javascript error, by The way)

Comment: Then the premise of the title is not correct.  There is no need to modify any JavaScript if you have a PHP problem.

Comment: I'm supposing... I don 't really know where the issue lays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for forgetting this question. A lot of time after this question, one friend of mine solved the problem for me. So, here is it.

When you transfer your code online you should check with a **phpinfo**(), a simple php function, which **version** of php the server support and what **services** are provided.

In this case this was a **json_encode**() problem. This function (obviously!) work only if you have the json service up and functioning. In my case, the server provide a quite old php version and json wasn't available and the result of the json_encode was meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/01/write-and-test-your-jquery-code-online.html   - here is online tools for validation of your code

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.